# How Deserialization works?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

As far as my understanding goes constructor of class whose Object is serialized is not called but the no-arg constructor of 1st non serializable constructor. Now consider following code

```
public class SerializeDemo implements Serializable {

private String name;
int age;    //default 0

public SerializeDemo(String name, boolean setAge){
    this.name = name;
    if(setAge){
        this.age = 18;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name is " + name + " and age is " + age;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("//home//aniket//Desktop//serializedObjects.txt")));
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("//home//aniket//Desktop//serializedObjects.txt")));
    SerializeDemo sd = new SerializeDemo("Test",true);
    System.out.println("Before Serialization : " + sd);
    oos.writeObject(sd);
    SerializeDemo sdCopy = (SerializeDemo)ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("After Deserialization : " + sdCopy);
}
}
```

and the output is(as expected)

```
Before Serialization : Name is Test and age is 18
After Deserialization : Name is Test and age is 18
```

Now the the non serializable super class having no-arg constructor is Object(Correct me if I am wrong). So basically SerializeDemo constructor is not called.

Now when the Object is created during deserialization it will try to rebuild the instance state. So it will set age to 18.

Question is how?

I have deliberately not provided the setter. Nor as per above discussion it's constructor is called. So how is it set?(Same goes for name as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at `ObjectInputStream` source code. It uses reflection, it creates an object, reads fields from stream, and sets object's fields using reflection. You can run your code in a debugger and go step by step exactly to the line where age is set.

Comment: Does it work in cases like ObjectInputStream? As I know you must provide non-argument constructor in class which implements Serializable interface but there are some classes like ObjectInputStream when lack of non-argument constructor does not make truble in deserialization. Am I right?

Comment: If class implements Serializable ObjectInputStream ignores its constructors, it creates an unitialized object and injects fields in it

Comment: Yes I understand this part, but if you send an object to another machine via RMI as I know you have to provide non-argument contructor in it.

Comment: RMI uses serialization in usual way, empty constructor is needed only for Externalizable objects

Comment: @biti No. Where did you get that from? RMI marshaling is no different from Object Serialization.

Answer (score 4):

> Now the the non serializable super class having no-arg constructor is Object.

Correct.

> So basically SerializeDemo constructor is not called.

Correct.

> Now when the Object is created during deserialization it will try to rebuild the instance state. So it will set age to 18.

Correct.

> Question is how?

Reflection ... with access checks turned off.

The class descriptor in the serialized class gives the name and type of all of the serialized fields.  The `Class` object defines `Field` objects for the actual class.  The deserialization code matches the available serialized fields to the `Field` objects, and then uses `Field.set(...)` methods to set the field values.

(In fact, this is an implementation detail, but that's my understanding of how it works in current generation JVMs.  You can always check the source code ...)

Comment: you were saying Object instance is created and injected with values got from stream. but what about the instance of the Actual class object which I tried to serialize who will create the instance for it ? and moreover why the field value are injected to the Object instance as those are not the properties of it but related to one of a child class. Please do explain!!

Comment: There is an `Unsafe` method that is used to do that.  Read the source code.